# Snowflake copies wrong data when using ext table + insert on azure storage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when using the following method the data is mangled.
the main issue pops up when the copying is of varchar columns. I'm aware of the copy from stage ,wthod, however it runs into issues when I try to run it on a parquet file.

```
create or replace stage azure_copy
  storage_integration = azure_tpcxbb
  url = '(location)'
  file_format = az_parquet (pre-defined);
  
  
  create or replace external table ext_customer_address
 with location = @azure_copy
 auto_refresh = false
  file_format = az_parquet
 pattern='.*[.]parquet';
 

insert into "TPCXBB"."PUBLIC"."customer_address" 
(    "ca_address_sk",
  "ca_address_id" ,
  "ca_street_number",
  "ca_street_name",
  "ca_street_type" ,
  "ca_suite_number",
  "ca_city",
  "ca_county",
  "ca_state" ,
  "ca_zip",
  "ca_country",
  "ca_gmt_offset",
  "ca_location_type")

select   $1:ca_address_sk,
  $1:ca_address_id ,
  $1:ca_street_number,
  $1:ca_street_name,
  $1:ca_street_type ,
  $1:ca_suite_number,
  $1:ca_city,
  $1:ca_county,
  $1:ca_state,
  $1:ca_zip,
  $1:ca_country,
  $1:ca_gmt_offset,
  $1:ca_location_type
from ext_customer_address;
```

Comment: It is helpful to describe the issues that you are seeing.  Also, if you plan on just inserting, rather than COPY INTO, you could probably do this with a straight select, rather than an external table, anyway.

Comment: we resorted to the ext table option after the straight method failed. specifically the "broken" columns were varchar formatted dates in a yyyy-mm-dd pattern, which were "translated" into number&letter strings and varchar letter codes that were "translated" into number strings

Comment: Can you help us reproduce the problem? Do you have a sample file? What do you mean by "data is mangled"? What are the issues?